# Code is taking so much time to execute?

Tags: java-8

```
Random random = new Random();
random.ints()
      .filter(e -> e<40 && e>1) 
      .limit(10)
      .sorted()
      .distinct()  
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

i need distinct data but faster too. By removing this distinct execution be a little faster

Comment: Rather than generating random integers and then looking for the tiny proportion of them in the range you care about, generate them in the range you care about in the first place.  [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-) describes how to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43490829/2711488), you should use the three-arg factory method rather than `filter` and `limit`. This avoids generating random values which you will drop afterwards. For some stream operations, it’s additionally beneficial to know the result stream size in advance (which non-intuitively doesn’t apply to `limit`).

Further, you should use `ThreadLocalRandom`, if you know that you are going to process the elements sequentially (otherwise, use `new SplittableRandom()`, if you are going to process a parallel stream).

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(10,2,40)
    .sorted()
    .distinct()  
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

If that’s still to expensive, use

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current().ints(10,2,40)
    .collect(BitSet::new, BitSet::set, BitSet::or)
    .stream()
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```

as a `BitSet` is intrinsically sorted and distinct. This is much more efficient than the current `IntStream` implementation, which will collect into an `int[]` array to sort the values and use a `HashSet<Integer>` to determine whether it has already seen values.

Comment: Side note: `BitSet` is only applicable iff the numbers are positive.

Comment: @Flown: and there should be a reasonable ratio between the value range and the number of elements to be efficient, i.e. if the values are very sparse, the Stream’s `HashMap` approach would be better. And if the value range (i.e. the minimum) is too far away from zero, it would be beneficial to maintain an offset instead of storing the `[0 … maximum]` range. I suppose, these are the reasons why the general purpose `IntStream` implementation doesn’t use that trick, supporting arbitrary use cases is much harder.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is producing random ints in the range from `Integer.MIN_VALUE` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. Only a tiny portion of those values fits your required bounds. So a huge amount of random numbers is generated of which you discard > 99% .... This costs a lot of time.

`Random` has a [3-arguments version](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-) of `ints()` that can replace half your code. The arguments are the streamsize, and the upper and lower bounds of the numbers.

Your code would look like this:

```
Random random = new Random();
random.ints(10,2,40)
      .sorted()
      .distinct()  
      .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Just notice that you're not guaranteed to get 10 numbers, since `distinct` is used after the streamsize is set.

Comment: yes your code is fast, but what is the reason my code is taking much time for execution ?

Comment: Your code was producing random ints in the range from Integer.MIN_VALUE to Integer.MAX_VALUE. Only a tiny portion of those values fits your required bounds. So a huge amount of random numbers is generated of which you discard > 99% ....